# make clean in CMake generated build system does not propagate into external projects

Tags: cmake

I am currently setting up a build system using CMake but I have some struggles with "make clean" in conjunction with external projects: I can't figure out why  "make clean" does not propagate down to the projects that I add via ExternalProject_Add.

My (minimalistic example) source structure looks like this:

```
/
|- test/
|  |- CMakeLists.txt
|  |- main.cpp
|  |- my_lib
|     |- CMakeLists.txt
|     |- lib_functions.cpp
```

In /test/CMakeLists.txt I use ExternalProject_Add to add my_lib:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# via external project
include(ExternalProject)
set(MY_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_lib)
ExternalProject_Add(ext_my_lib
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib
    BINARY_DIR ${MY_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
add_library(my_lib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MY_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}/libmy_lib.a)
add_dependencies(my_lib
    ext_my_lib
    )

set(PROJECT_NAME my_test)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} my_lib)
```

And /test/my_lib/CMakeLists.txt is just a simple library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(PROJECT_NAME my_lib)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} lib_functions.cpp)
```

After generating build system from /test/CMakeLists.txt I call "make" and then "make clean", but my_lib is not cleaned, i. e. the file build/my_lib/libmy_lib.a is not deleted. 
In contrast when I direclty call "make clean" in the build/my_lib directory "make clean -C my_lib" my_lib is cleaned correctly, i. e. the file build/my_lib/libmy_lib.a IS deleted. 
This makes me assume that somehow the "make clean" is not correctly propagated down to the external project, but I cannot figure out why.

I know that I could use add_subdirectory by replacing the "# via external project" section in the /test/CMakeLists.txt file by

```
# via add_subdirectory
set(MY_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_lib)
add_subdirectory(my_lib ${MY_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR})
```

Using this way the "make clean" works correctly, i. e. build/my_lib/libmy_lib.a is deleted, but I need to work with external projects due to other reasons.

I also know that I could define ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES, e. g.

```
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES
    ${MY_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}
    )
```

but this would

- also delete the build system for my_lib
- not call "make clean" on dependencies inside of /test/my_lib/CMakeLists.txt

so that is not a solution for me.

Comment: Looks like CMake doesn't allow to add actions for "clean" step except setting *ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES* property. Because `ExternalProject` is just a common CMake module, which uses CMake commands and has no access to CMake internals, it cannot call `make clean` for external project at "clean" stage for main project. [ In other words, there is no error in `ExternalProject` module. But the question "how to do <this> in CMake" by itself is perfectly OK. May be someone else will answer on it.]

Comment: I am also interested in this. Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I didn't resolve it. I just went for the unsatisfying ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES approach as described above.